# Determine numerical values for PlotRange when using Plotrange->All

Tags: plotting

Say I create a plot using `Show` and use the option `PlotRange->All`, for instance

```
surf[u_,v_]:={(1-u*Sin[v/2])*Cos[v], (1-u*Sin[v/2])*Sin[v],u*Cos[v/2]};
partdif1[u_,v_] := (D[surf[x,y],x] /. x -> u) /. y -> v;
partdif2[u_,v_] := (D[surf[x,y],y] /. x -> u) /. y -> v;
cpdiffs[u_,v_] := (Cross[partdif1[x, y], partdif2[x, y]] /. x -> u) /. y -> v;
NV[u_, v_] := -0.8*cpdiffs[u, v]/Norm[cpdiffs[u, v]];
surfplot = ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -1/4, 1/4}, {v, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> "DeepSeaColors", Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];
nvect = Graphics3D[{Black, Thickness[0.004], Arrow[{surf[0, 0], surf[0, 0] + NV[0, 0]}]}];

Show[surfplot, nvect, PlotRange -> All]
```

How can I extract the numerical values of the plot range? I want to use the values in a Wolframscript, so please no clicking solution.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[surfplot, PlotRange]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sh = Show[surfplot, nvect, PlotRange -> All];

pr = AbsoluteOptions[sh, PlotRange]
```

{PlotRange -> {{-1.25, 1.8}, {-1.17678, 1.17678}, {-0.25, 0.25}}}

To extract the values:

```
Values @ First @ pr
```

{{-1.25, 1.00764}, {-1.17678, 1.17678}, {-0.25, 0.25}}

```
Show[sh, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! Many thanks! Could you explicitetly give the command that gives the values only?

Comment: Thanks for the accept. To get the values only: `Values@First@AbsoluteOptions[sh, PlotRange]`